# Is "give" or "gives" the correct way in this case?

Tags: verbs, subject-verb-agreement, verb-usage

I am trying to understand what form is correct in this sentence.

- **"Full access" gives/give permission to see the report about scheduled hours.**

For context, we are explaining what "full access" vs "limited access" provides.
Is it third-person singular form, aka, *gives permission*?

Comment: *gives* is correct

Comment: You mentioned that you're thinking that it's singular. Could you edit to explain why you might have some uncertainty—maybe there's more context? If this answer is closed because it lacks that, feel free to edit so it can be reopened.